# Laptop fans go wild after waking from suspend 13.10

Tags: 13.10, laptop, hp, fan, temperature

When my laptop wakes up from suspend the fans start running at 100%. I've look around all over the place but I can't find an answer. Only a reboot fixes the problem. It is a HP ProBook 4510s

I've installed lm-sensors and this is the output when I run sensors.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +16.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)
temp2:        +26.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp3:        +32.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)
temp4:        +37.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp5:        +20.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)
temp6:        +90.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +30.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +31.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

temp6 is showing 90 degrees even though it isn't, but it never goes down unless I reboot.
I'm not sure what temp6 is but I suspect it may be a motherboard sensor.

**Edit**
I looked for suspicious activity in the System Monitor, there was none.